# JavaScript: Limit number of checked allowed boxes based on unique CLASS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Java-Script code

```
var maxCheckedCount = 3;
var CLASS = 'Woops! Too many selected!';

    jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        var n = jQuery('input:checked').length;
        if(n>=maxCheckedCount){
            jQuery(this).prop('checked',false);
            alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
        }
    });
```

and then here is HTML check-boxes list.

```
<input type="checkbox">1
<br>
<input type="checkbox">2
<br>
<input type="checkbox">3
<br>
<input type="checkbox">4
<br>
<input type="checkbox">5
<br>


<ul   CLASS="options-34-list">
<li>
<input type="checkbox">6
</li>
<input type="checkbox">7
<li>
<input type="checkbox">8
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox">9
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox">10
</li>
</ul>
```

How can i only apply the JavaScript of limiting the allowed number of boxes based on the CLASS **CLASS="options-34-list"** of the checkbox not to all list.

Comment: You can't have more one element with the same id. id is unique

Comment: First thoughts: don't use id for this. Always use unique `id`s. Use classes.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, i will modify it now

Comment: [The id attribute must be unique in a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Apart of that, what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my version!

```
$.fn.maxSelectedCheckboxes = maxSelectedCheckboxes;

function maxSelectedCheckboxes(maxSelected) {
    var $targets = this;
    $targets.on('click', function() {
        var $checked = $targets.filter(':checked');
        if ($checked.length > maxSelected) {
            $checked.not(this).first().removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S8ZTA/

It's nice because it can be used on any selector applied across a collection of checkboxes:

```
$('#options-34-list input[type="checkbox"]').maxSelectedCheckboxes(3);
```

Comment: +1 Upvote, Nice answer! :-) although for personal preference, I dislike the `var $$ =` could see that leading to confusion!

Comment: Haha I hated myself when I wrote `$$`! Now that I look back, I think I'd go with `$targets`.

Comment: Thank you Benastan. Your answer is even better than i expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) to search for nodes inside the descendants of a given node.

Number of checked items found inside the list `#options-34-list` :

```
$('#options-34-list').find('input:checked').length
```

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute must be unique, you can use a class instead.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox">1
<br>
<input type="checkbox">2
<br>
<input type="checkbox">3
<br>
<input type="checkbox">4
<br>
<input type="checkbox">5
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="options-34-list">6
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="options-34-list">7
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="options-34-list">8
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="options-34-list">9
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="options-34-list">10
<br>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var n = jQuery('.options-34-list:checked').length;
    if (n > maxCheckedCount) {
        jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ATbvM/